# how to get suggestions using opensearch?

Tags: opensearch

I have created a function gets google suggestions and returns it in the same format. My `opensearch.xml` file is as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<OpenSearchDescription xmlns="http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearch/1.1/" xmlns:suggestions="http://www.opensearch.org/specifications/opensearch/extensions/suggestions/1.1">
    <ShortName>example</ShortName>
    <Description>example</Description>
    <InputEncoding>UTF-8</InputEncoding>
    <Url type="application/x-suggestions+json" template="https://<url>/meta_search/get_suggestions/?query={searchTerms}" method="get" />
</OpenSearchDescription>
```

When i type "iphone" in address bar using my site as search engine get this:
[image]

But when i type "iphone" in address bar using google as search engine get these suggestions:
[image]

How can get the same suggestions using my website as search engine?

Comment: [For anyone still wondering](https://github.com/MintPlayer/MintPlayer.AspNetCore.OpenSearch/blob/master/MintPlayer.AspNetCore.OpenSearch/Extensions/OpenSearch.cs#L43-L89)